# Is it possible to use High order functions with optional arguments

Tags: kotlin

I put together a dummy problem to illustrate my point: Say that we have the following handy function to display information about a particular sorting algorithm:

```
fun sort(name: String, array: Array<Int>, sortingAlgorithm: (Array<Int>) -> Array<Int>) {
    println(name)
    sortingAlgorithm(array).forEach { print(" $it ") }
    println()
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
sort("Selection Sort - Θ(n^2)", arrayOf(2, 3, 1), ::selectionSort)
```

And this works because the signature of `selectionSort` is simple: `fun selectionSort(array: Array<Int>): Array<Int> {`

But say I have another sorting algorithm with the following signature

```
fun quickSort(array: Array<Int>,
              start: Int = 0,
              end: Int = array.size - 1): Array<Int> {
```

The last two arguments are optional, so in theory you could call `quickSort` the same way you call `selectionSort`. That is to say, it stil respects the signature `(Array<Int>) -> Array<Int>` Right?

Unfortunately when I try to call `sort("Quick Sort", arrayOf(2, 3, 1), ::quickSort)` I get:

[image: type missmatch]

I think that the compiler isn't being smart enough to realise that those two arguments are optional. How can avoid this problem, other than overloading the `sort` method to accept a high order function with the signature ?

Comment: Can't you just use a lambda expression instead of the method reference?

Comment: you mean like this: sort("Quick Sort", { quickSort(unsorted) }), yes, that works! but I was just wondering why the other way around doesn't. It feels that it should work as well.

Comment: thumb up  for finding such impractical question :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no avoiding this problem since it would contradict 2 corner stones of Kotlin type system:

- 1) Every expression has a type (strong typing)
- 2) The receiver side does not affect an expression's type (local inference)

For example if you could do that, the following would not to work, which is a simple refactoring of your example:

```
val algorithm = ::quickSort
sort("Quick Sort", arrayOf(2, 3, 1), algorithm)
```

Anyways, the `sort("Quick Sort", { quickSort(unsorted) })` workaround is too simple for Kotlin developers to spend spend time on the problem.